# Man buys item, throws it away on his way out

Tags: lateral-thinking

I thought of this lateral thinking puzzle. Hopefully, it's not too broad and hasn't been asked before.

> A man walks into a store, buys an item for $1, and throws it away along with the receipt on his way out. What item did he buy?

Notes:

- His decision to throw the item away on his way out was completely justified.
- He did not put anything in his mouth between buying the item and throwing it away.

EDIT: To make this question less broad, here are some notes that I should've had in the beginning:

- He bought the item because he wanted the item.
- "Throw away" means he put the item and the receipt in the trash can.
- The item was reasonably priced at 1 USD in 2018.
- He threw the item away because his perception of the item's intrinsic value changed.

Comment: There are other reasons to share one's thoughts than having them rewarded as uniquely best. ^_^

Comment: Hi, I’m relatively new. I just wanted to say I enjoyed reading through the unique and creative answers, so I think I am a fan of broader lateral thinking questions. Reading a little about the community rules I see how and why this sort of thing may be discouraged. Anyway, I am not here to break rules or join an argument, just wanted to voice my opinion 

Comment: @kedarguru My question was originally too broad but I edited my question to add a few more details that invalidate most answers. So it shouldn't be too broad now.

Comment: @Alconja, well in that case the Q should be downvoted because too many answers can be correct, thus it is an open-ended question and should be discouraged.

Comment: @Octopus There are many here who would in fact agree with what you've said.

Comment: @rluks Welcome to Puzzling! (Take our [Tour]!) Please don't post answers in comments - the question is protected for a reason, and circumventing that is quite inappropriate.  Your comment was deleted.

Comment: **25 people** have answered this question as of this point, the vast majority of which did so after an answer was already accepted. You're obviously not trying to find the correct solution, you're trying to find other clever or unusual answers which are Not Wrong for the puzzle as written. ***Why?*** Yes, it's fun, but almost every answer beyond the accepted one is either a dup, ignores part of the question, or is so illogical that the explanation for the action stretches credulity beyond all reason. [tag:lateral-thinking] is not code for "anything goes". Please, don't answer just to answer.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It was

> A scratch card. And presumably not a winning one.

Comment: Well, that was fast :)

Comment: They seem to cost $2 these days... Must be inflation.

Comment: Seeing the puzzle title from HNQ, this was my _immediate_ thought.

Comment: Who gets a receipt for a scratcher?

Comment: @MichaelHampton There's plenty of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, and 20 dollar scratchers at most retail and convenience stores here, so it might be a regional thing.

Comment: @NuclearWang I don't know, but I just didn't want people to think along the lines of "he just wanted the receipt" so I made him throw it away.

Comment: This may be the first puzzle in PSE I've ever got right before reading the accepted answer

Comment: AFAIK, people buy scratch cards but do not immediately scratch them. They do that at home as they normally have other items to worry about. It is rare for someone to go to a store just to buy a $1 scratch card.

Comment: @Phil some people scratch them at the store, and often times you don't even need to scratch the whole card, you can just scratch the area that hides a 3 or 4 digit code that the cashier can scan to determine how much was won.... most boring way to play a scratcher, but it's how my brother plays.

Answer (score 110):

Perhaps he really needed to

> use the restroom, but the store has a strict customer-only policy.

In this case, what he bought was

> completely inconsequential.

Comment: I've done this once at McDonald's - I've bought a ketchup package...

Comment: @vaxquis I paid a nickle for a cup of water once.  I didn't even know you can buy a packet of ketchup.

Comment: @Nelson Some franchise owners are cheapskates and try to cut costs by limiting the number of condiment packages a customer can have, extras cost more.  For example, if you get a burger and fries, you might get 3 packets as part of the meal but if you want more, they charge you per pack.

Comment: @AndyT this happened to me only once, because I've only found one McD restaurant that indeed had their restrooms restricted, IMVHO mostly because it was in Zakopane, Poland - a city that has *tons* of mountain tourists, and thus *extremely* long restroom queues with absurdly long wait times. I suppose they did it so that *their* customers can use the restrooms *at all*.

Comment: I once bought a candy bar because I needed change, and the store wouldn’t make change except in conjunction with a purchase. Of course I ate it, but if the store didn’t have anything I could use (or resell), I might buy something and immediately throw it away.

Answer (score 80):

> He bought a newspaper, turned to the classifieds section, and read an ad. Then he threw away the newspaper. The ad could be anything: a secret spy communication, or a response to a proposal, or a code that's part of some puzzle game.

Comment: I applaud the integrity of a man who would pay for a newspaper he only intended to glance at.

Comment: True, though proprietors frown on people opening up newspapers that are for sale. I personally think it’s not okay to do that!

Comment: Buy a newspaper, pull out the advertising insert with coupons, throw newspaper away, use coupons to get well over a dollar discount on shopping elsewhere.

Comment: @AllenR.Brady If he's a spy, then confusion is part of the business.

Comment: You are over-complicating things. Plus, sending covert info via newspapers is so 1970's. Just post stuff on facebook... It has so much data that no one will notice or think it is "fake news."

Comment: @Phil I reject your value judgment. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: @Phil "so 1970s"  That kind of thinking actually makes it a good transmission medium.

Comment: @Phil I think the 2010s way of transmitting secret information is via comments in Puzzling.SE in the attic.

Comment: @JiK Yeah like anyone's really going to use that method nowadays.... To CT Merry Anniversay Darling.We shall take a walk by the river at 5pm tonight when I shall give you the presents from your two gorgeous children  Kitty

Comment: Not terribly far fetched, but there can be a significant cost (especially if done often) to placing the ad, and a significant lead time between placing the ad and having it available to read. By "Significant", I mean compared to posting somewhere online (Facebook for example, as others have mentioned). Plus, for a spy, there's the added complication of anonymizing the payment for the classified ad. Plus, why ***buy*** a paper for only a quick glance, when there are so many places to view newspapers (without purchasing) like a library, or waiting area, or some restaurants, coffee shops, etc...

Comment: @KevinFegan Bah Humbug! I mentioned two other reasons besides spy communication. All that's necessary is plausibility, not likelihood. :)

Comment: Yes, that's why my first sentence indicates your idea is plausible. It's just a comment. I didn't downvote your answer, and I didn't suggest it's not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @JiK "The pigeons are flying low in Maryland this spring"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I noticed that last week children seemed to prefer playing in Huntington Park rather than flying their kites at the sea. We should consider buying them presents and introducing them to your sister.

Comment: Reminds me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW5EiGwi_a8

Answer (score 78):

Sounds like

> A towel/handkerchief. He cleaned himself with it and tossed it out.

Comment: I think this is the second-best answer (after the accepted one)

Comment: So disgusting. But I like it.

Comment: Any single-use personal hygiene item (except a toothbrush as that goes in the mouth) or repair item (i.e. a cheap sewing kit or eyeglass screwdriver) would fit your idea.

Comment: You can probably buy a "sample size" packet of wet wipes for $1.

Comment: I had this thought, too, but $1 for one single use towel seems like a bit of a rip off, lol.

Comment: You can get a paper towel for free... So why spend a $1.

Answer (score 66):

Yes, this is clearly the intended solution...

> The man went into a dollar store in Australia, and bought one of those cheap souvenir boomerangs. He was justified in throwing it away on his way out as he expected it to return to him.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why he threw the receipt with it, though...

Comment: @AndyJuell he trained with the receipt first

Comment: This is a duplicate answer, yet somehow got 20 more upvotes than the [original answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64145/4450).

Comment: @pacoverflow Oops, I did a quick scan for this answer but apparently msised it. Do I delete my answer?

Comment: No need...yours was evidently better written (mine did have a typo for much of the interim).  Thanks for the thought, though. :)

Comment: What adult do you know throws boomerangs in stores? And if you know anyone, which one you know throws them along with a receipt?

Answer (score 60):

> A cheap plastic boomerang.  After catching it, being a responsible chap, he then picked up the receipt and deposited it in the recycling bin.

Comment: Wow, you posted 2 hours before another guy with the same answer, and he got 20 upvotes.

Answer (score 49):

For some reason,

> the man was in a desperate need to know the time. Receipts have timestamps printed on them

Comment: Nah. He would turn around and ask the nearest person the time. That is free.

Comment: @Phil I know this sounds as an ad-hoc hypothesis, but he might be an undercover time traveler.

Comment: Maybe he has a huge social anxiety or he has no common language with the local people. Most likely both.

Comment: Not a very reliable way - timestamps on receipt are often couple of hours off.

Comment: @zagad Really? Surprised to hear that. That woul dmean they sometimes show the wrong date and even the wrong fiscal year. - But maybe I just live closer to Switzerland than you ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen where I live, shops tend to close for 15 minutes around midnight. I always thought badly programmed cash desks can't handle wrong dates.

Answer (score 42):

> It was 1965, and OP had just been to the Cinema to watch a movie.
> On leaving the premises, OP throws away the ticket stub, which is also a receipt because it is proof of payment.
> **Answer:  OP threw away a movie ticket stub.**. 
> Approximate value of a movie ticket over time  http://www.boxofficemojo.com/about/adjuster.htm
> OP might have watched:
>  * The Sound Of Music (Family)
>  * For a Few Dollars More (Western)
> * Doctor Zhivago
>  * Thunderball (Bond)
>   from https://www.ranker.com/list/best-movies-of-1965/ranker-film

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you please add spoilertags to your answer?

Comment: For a Few Dollars More he could've gotten some snacks too.

Comment: Doesn't have to be that far back. In the late 90s, I was paying $1 for that. As long you didn't mind waiting a little.

Comment: @ikegami you're right, but was trying to not be tied to any specific currency.      There are 37 different dollars active in the world and 4 former dollar economies, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar#Other_national_currencies_called_%E2%80%9Cdollar%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 40):

Alternate answer:

> A top-up card for his mobile/cell-phone.
>  He entered the scratch-and-see code, got his top-up and chucked the card and receipt in the bin as he made his call/responded to a text message.

Comment: For $1? _<padding>_

Comment: In many countries a dollar will get a reasonable amount of mobile usage.

Comment: This makes sense.

Answer (score 27):

> A flower for his SO who promptly broke up with him before he left the store (possibly over the phone).

Comment: lol, maybe that was justified if he was only willing to spend $1 :)

Comment: Or a political campaign button for a candidate, who has a scandal break as the man is walking out of the store.

Comment: I doubt that has ever happened.

Comment: Do you ***buy*** campaign buttons (or other adware like tee-shirts and bumper stickers)? I thought the campaign gave them out.

Answer (score 17):

Alternate answer:

> He put $1 of fuel for the pump that his car is at. The item the clerk handed him *was the receipt*.

Comment: +1 Creative answer, but I don't think you can *buy a receipt*

Comment: Also $1 of gas wouldn't get you very far!

Comment: @IanF1 Could be returning a rental and _just_ had to get it to half.

Comment: In my country there is a minimum amount of gas per transaction, which is more than 1$ worth of fuel.

Comment: @RickvanOsta How would that work for things like lawn mowers and scooters? I have a scooter with a gallon tank, so I typically only put in $0.50 at a time.

Comment: @IanF1 \$1 is what I pay to drive ~20 miles. So, when I start my kids in school, \$1 should be enough to cover about a week's worth of trips when it's too cold to walk.

Comment: @phyrfox You’d drive your lawn mower to the gas station? Haha. I have no clue, the minimum is 2 liters usually, which is less than a gallon. However, a single liter costs about €1.55 (\$1.91) so you’d pay more than $4 here to top off your scooter. Gas prices suck.

Comment: There was a day I left home without my purse and bought gas with the change on the floor of my car to get home.

Answer (score 13):

He bought:

> some eggs which broke after purchasing and thus dejected, he threw both the eggs and the receipt away...

Checks all the given conditions...

Answer (score 12):

Well, he could've bought

> some kind of a top-up card, topped up whatever he had to and then on his way out, chucked the used up card and the receipt out...

Edit:
Errm, looks like someone just said the same thing. Hell, in fact even used similar words. lol

Comment: Great minds think alike! :)

Comment: Haha! I guess so!

Answer (score 11):

Alternate answer:

> he bought some paper and made a plane with it, then he threw it in the wind :D

Comment: I've never seen a stack of  paper that costs $1 lol :P

Comment: @North I have.  12" x 12" scrapbooking pages at Joann are often in that price range.  Of course, paper airplanes are typically made from 8.5"x11" in my experience...

Comment: @ArcanistLupus standard paper planes are of course made of A4 paper, though

Comment: @njzk2 I *knew* someone was going to bring that up. Regardless, they're still rectangular.

Comment: @North - Here in US (at least locally), you can get a pack (maybe 15 to 25 sheets) of 8.5 x 11 paper for $1 at a dollar store.

Comment: That's a lot of paper planes. I like it.

Comment: @KevinFegan Umm I live in the U.S. I just never seen paper for $1 :P

Answer (score 10):

> He bought an envelope/stamp (or other small package) and threw it into the mail dropoff. The receipt could have been separately thrown into a trash bin.

Answer (score 9):

This might be a bit gross but...

He bought a

> condom, used it,

then on the way out he threw it away.

Comment: "He threw the item away because his perception of the item's intrinsic value changed."

Comment: Sure, it's value would certainly change based on the situation I described.

Comment: He used a condom, in the store, with the cashier(?) then threw it out?

Answer (score 7):

I think ...

> He bought a parking token. Once he used and drove out, he threw it away. The receipt he got is for the card swipe he made at the store.

Answer (score 5):

The man bought

> a perishable item (e.g. milk, yogurt, etc).  After he paid for it and before consuming it, he noticed that the expiration date already passed, so he threw it away.

Comment: Unless he's very short of time the usual reaction would be to go back to the counter and exchange the item for one which hasn't expired.

Answer (score 4):

> Pretty sure he bought one of those lucky charm clovers you get when
>  you donate a dollar to the store's charity and realized it didn't have
>  a scratch off lottery ticket on the back of it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the man bought a

> packet of crisps but realized they were not vegetarian friendly.

I have done this 2/3 times.

Comment: Why wouldn't you give it away to someone who would eat it?

Comment: @mbomb007 veg[etari]ans are animal friendly

Comment: @sehe The chips are already made and created. It's fine to be animal friendly, but you should also be people friendly and feed someone with the food. If I mistakenly got something without meat, I'm not going to throw it away because I'm not vegetarian. Eat it or give it away.

Comment: In some countries it is rude to give away opened food like that.

Answer (score 0):

he bought a

> trash bag (a very small trash can could fit). Since there is no info on this man, it seems reasonable that he takes care of refitting the trash on the street.

Comment: I don't think that satisfies the last criterion.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps:

> He wanted to check the price of a particular stock in which he had a large investment, so he bought a newspaper like the *Wall Street Journal* or the *Financial Times*, checked the price he was interested in, and then tossed it.

Comment: But he threw the item away because of a loss of perceived intrinsic value. Also your answer is the same as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64134/41566)