# My infix is the price that my suffix asks to pay

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

My first '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)':

> My prefix is dishonest, in everything they say,
>
> My infix is the price, that my suffix asks to pay.

**What am I?**

Comment: I think the new tag `riley-puzzle` might be better if it were changed to `riley-riddle`, since @Riley has made many puzzles (e.g. [this lateral-thinking puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64123/man-buys-item-throws-it-away-on-his-way-out)).

Comment: I removed that tag, since [we decided in the meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag) that we don't want one.

Comment: @Bass I didn't know about that; I am very sorry for starting up this tag idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NEW GUESS:**

You are

> Concentrate

My prefix is dishonest, in everything they say,

> Con as in con-man.

My infix is the price

> Cent

that my suffix asks to pay.

> Rate

---

Probably wrong but it doesn't hurt to guess.

> Liability

My prefix is dishonest, in everything they say,

> Liar

My infix is the price

> Bill

that my suffix asks to pay.

> Ability

Comment: interesting answer, but not quite there, prefix needed an extra letter in your guess. good try anyway.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I have another guess. Is it ROT13(pbapragengvba)? If it is, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: almost got it, need some modification, you're on the right track .

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Is it just ROT13(pbapragengr)?

Comment: this time, you got it

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stretch, but could the hidden word be

> **LIEUTENANT**?

`My prefix is dishonest, in everything they say.`

> **LIE**.

`My infix is the price,`

> **UTE**, short for **utility**.

`that my suffix asks to pay.`

> **NANTS** could stand for **New ANTenna (Sub)System**, which I guess must live up to the standard of being an electrical **utility** (referring to one of the main house-hold utilities; i.e. **electricity**, gas, water, **cable** and telephone. Do not get confused with an [*electric* utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_utility) even though that could be related.)

Comment: thanks for trying. but not what i had in mind.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid it included the `wordplay` tag in there, so I thought I was onto something with the infix and suffix; and given that the word "they" is used in the riddle instead of "it", I thought the answer might have been a plural. But, my answer was not intended. Oh well :)

Comment: keep trying, maybe you'll get it, right now @Kevorobin has the better answer..

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid After I answered and realised it was not correct, I moved on to my next riddle I made. I will now get back to this riddle... :)