# My second Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix is rejection, my infix is option,
>
> My suffix is a road we take to reach destination.

**Tell me who am I?**

**Hint:**

> it is a country.

---

**Note:** You can check out my first Riley riddle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69360/my-first-riley-riddle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Norway

My prefix is rejection

> No

my infix is option

> Or

My suffix is a road we take to reach destination.

> Way

Comment: got this one right as well..

Answer (score 0):

May be the answer is...

> Norway

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. You provided an answer which has already been given. Also, you need to explain why you think this is the correct answer or otherwise you might get downvoted.

Comment: welcome to PSE,do check the help option in your profile, specifically the question and answer parts, it will be much helpful for you. Keep puzzling, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be

> Norway

Comment: Please provide explanations as to how you arrived at your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, thanks for answering my puzzle,for future reference, do try to provide your workings, as to how you came to the answer and how it fits with the question.here's an up-vote to welcome and motivate you to keep puzzling. @arnab